# Hardhat how always sync the mainnet node states?

Tags: hardhat

I wanna to create an application for simulate transacation with Hardhat networking forking feature (check the ERC20 token buy and sell tax fee, just like https://honeypot.is/)

I try to config `mining mode` to `auto` or `interval`. But it just mine a fake block (not real sync with mainnet), So I cannot get real data from mainnet.

In order to always sync with mainnet, I have to restart hardhat networking forking every `12s`(the normal block generation time in ethereum). It is painful.

Thanks